# Apple Developer Program and Push Notification certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I recently purchased Apple Developer Program, but some things are struggling with me. I made an Add ID, and a push notification certificate on that App ID. Whenever I am trying to activate Push notification in my project, i can just se the default options. Do i have to create a new team or something after this purchase? Or a profile?
Here is some images of whats happening in my xcode project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Whenever i am changing the Bundle ID, this message pops up, even if i am a member of the Developer Program..

Comment: Did you try changing `com.gustavwww.notifme` to something else? (eg. `com.gustavwww.ynotif`)

Comment: @I'L'I This gives me another message, even tho i am a member of the Developer Program: 'The 'Apple Push Notification' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit 
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll.'

Comment: What are the options you have in the pull-down menu. "Personal Team" might not be the correct one to use.

Comment: @I'L'I I´d also have my name (Only) to choose from, but that gives the first result.

Comment: I think you'll need to download your developer signing certificates  from the member center, then they will show up there.

Comment: Solved, all i did was changing team to only myself in the option, and then connecting a device. Thats all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the right team selected in your project preferences.